# Attached Property does not work as expected

Tags: .net, wpf

I'd like to create a control that only shows items that fit into the bounds of the control. For that I created my own panel that inherits from `StackPanel` and overrode the `ArrangeOverride` procedure. There I let the default `StackPanel` do the arranging and afterwards I detect the items that don't fit into the bounds of my panel and hide them. This works like a charm.

Now I'd like to know whether an item has been hidden because of not fitting into the bounds of my panel. For that I created an attached property which I set to `True` in case of hiding the item. And I bound a property in my view model to this attached property. But I never get the information, whether or not the item has been hidden.

For the sake of simplicity I created a little sample project which shows my problem but without all the overhead.

I hope one of you can figure out why I don't get the information I long for.

---

Here's my `StackPanel`. In every second item my attached property "Test" of type `String` is set to "Filled", otherwise it's default value is "Empty".

```
Public Class StackPanelEx
    Inherits StackPanel

    Public Shared TestProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Test", GetType(String), GetType(StackPanelEx), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Empty"))

    Public Shared Function GetTest(ByVal d As DependencyObject) As String
        Return d.GetValue(StackPanelEx.TestProperty)
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub SetTest(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal value As String)
        d.SetValue(StackPanelEx.TestProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function ArrangeOverride(finalSize As Size) As Size
        Dim result As Size

        Dim index As Integer

        result = MyBase.ArrangeOverride(finalSize)

        For Each child As UIElement In MyBase.InternalChildren
            index += 1

            If (index Mod 2) = 0 Then
                StackPanelEx.SetTest(child, "Filled")
            End If
        Next child

        Return result
    End Function

End Class
```

Here's my ItemViewModel, plain and simple:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ItemViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Private _caption As String

    Public Property Caption As String
        Get
            Return _caption
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _caption = value
            Me.OnPropertyChanged(NameOf(Me.Caption))
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

And here's my MainViewModel, containing a collection of ItemViewModels:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MainViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Private ReadOnly _items As ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)

    Public Sub New()
        _items = New ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)

        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Caption = "Item 1"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Caption = "Item 2"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Caption = "Item 3"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Caption = "Item 4"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Caption = "Item 5"})
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Items As ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)
        Get
            Return _items
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

And finally here's my MainWindow, you probably have to adjust the "local" namespace:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      MinWidth="50">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <local:StackPanelEx Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Caption}" Margin="2" local:StackPanelEx.Test="{Binding Caption, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

All the items show "Empty" as their caption, so the default value of my attached property works. But I'd expect every second item to show the caption "Filled" (because of setting the attached property's value in the `ArrangeOverride` of my panel).

Snoop shows me, that the value of my attached property is indeed "Filled" in every second item, so there seems to be a problem in my bindings.

And I can't figure out, where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Button in the ItemTemplate is not a direct child of your StackPanelEx that is used as ItemsPanel, hence the attached property is never set on the Button.

The ItemsControl creates a `ContentPresenter` as an *item container* element, which gets its `ContentTemplate` property set to the `ItemTemplate`.

Move your Binding to an `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    ...
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="local:StackPanelEx.Test"
                    Value="{Binding Caption, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```